# Reload Isotope "Show all" filter after showing hidden div

Tags: refresh, show-hide, reload, jquery-isotope

I have made a collapsible section for the portfolio (extensive) gallery on my one page website. The gallery has Isotope filters applied to it. On default only the header is shown, but when clicking on the header, the filter names and gallery should be unhidden (content hidden via CSS using display:none) as per JQuery code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('h5').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("open");
        $(this).next().toggle();
    }); //end toggle
}); //end ready
```

When I click the header, it expands the filter names, but gallery content isn't displayed. This only happens after clicking one of the filters. When toggling the collapsible section, the gallery remains shown as intended.

So the only problem is the initial unhiding of the gallery. I think by clicking the header, the "Show all" filter or other relevant div has to be reloaded/refreshed in order for the gallery to appear. I've tried multiple commands, but can't seem to find the correct one.

Thank you for the help and let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Either a link to the site or a fiddle would be very helpful.

Comment: Pixelsmith, have you had the time to check the link below? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the delay, but please find setup via link below:

http://www.davidmaes.eu/#work

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the site and isotope doesn't have time to calculate the image sizes, so it's giving the UL container a height of 0: `<ul class="portfolio-wrap isotope" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 0px;">` which is why the images aren't showing up.

When the user clicks a filter, isotope recalculates the images sizes and applies it to the UL, and voila, the images reappear.

You can manage this by using the [imagesloaded script](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/), which will only call isotope once the images have finished loading.

Here's the [isotope documentation](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/appendix.html) on integrating isotope with imagesloaded.